# How might I add a global function to jQuery .load -> .complete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

Writing a plugin for [top-secret] (not really :P) and I decided that one best course of action would be "IF" there is a definitive way to add function to ... maybe the $.ajax's complete func so that after a change is made, every new call to .load will call this implemented function automajically upon completion.

That's the idea in a nutshell, to break it down more (and no there isn't really code, because everything i have coded is working fine, this part i'm not sure where to start, duh1) If a user clicks on a link and a view-partial is loaded into an element, i log it and make a change to data field.  What i'd like to do, is have this happen on every instance of .load without having to make the coder add it to his/her code in the .load complete func.

Not sure how I cn make this make more since, although i don't "think" I did too bad.  Who kows i might find the answer myself as i'm looking through the jQuery library now.  If I do I'll post it, if not, hopefully someone has done something like this with "jQuery" before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, you could use [`ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/), that gets called whenever an AJAX request finishes.

> Edit to show use and work-ability

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ alert('complete'); });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4CK7q/

Comment: yeah, i was looking into that but you set it per element level nd i really want a global change, working with ajaxSetup now to try and achieve it but it's not firing under all clauses

Comment: @SpYk3HH `ajaxComplete()` is global, the examples in the docs are somewhat missleading, it is not bound to a specific element. See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gPzvP/

Comment: Ya know, I thought it should be global, since that what it says, I just don't understand the need for the element pretext. I tried it, and sure enough, it does work using pretty much whatever i put in the `("")`.  Seems odd they ddnt just make it `$.ajaxComplete()`.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I totally agree with you, i don't understand either why it is not just `$.ajaxComplete()`

Comment: lol, i did find one veritable problem, it doesn't "add a function" per say as much as it sets one, this could be a problem if the coder needs to use the function elsewhere, thus i guess the reason for the use of a blank element, testing it with multiple blanks now.